# Trying to add up the values of every node in a binary tree, recursively

Tags: c, recursion, binary-tree

I keep getting an error for invalid operand in return expression, I'm trying to recursively code a function to take every value in two different trees and add them together to create one tree but I keep getting an error, any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
node_t * addTree(node_t * t1, node_t * t2)
{
  if(t1 != NULL || t2 != NULL)
  {
    t1->data = t1->data + t2->data;
    return addTree(t1=t1->rightchild, t2=t2->rightchild)+addTree(t1=t1->rightchild, t2=t2->leftchild)+addTree(t1=t1->leftchild, t2=t2->rightchild)+addTree(t1=t1->leftchild, t2=t2->leftchild);
  }
  else
    return t1;
}
```

Comment: Your usage of assignment to `t1` and `t2` doesn't look good because the order of evaluation of each operands of `+` is not specified.

Comment: Yeah, when you write `t1=`, that is an assignment and it causes the value of t1 to change.  That is very risky if you are accessing `t1` in other parts of the code which are not separated from that assignment by a "sequence point".  I think you didn't mean to do that, and should remove all of the `t1=` and `t2=` from the code.  Also, please tell us exactly what the compiler error is.

Comment: Pardon the obvious, but why are you modifying nodes? Enumerating the tree recursively for value accumulation shouldn't need to modify *anything*; it should just accumulate and eventually return a value, not a node pointer. (quite possible I misunderstood the question title).

Comment: @JimHalpert This if statement   if(t1 != NULL || t2 != NULL)
  {
    t1->data = t1->data + t2->data; invokes undefined behavior.

Comment: @JimHalpert The function does not make a sense. Also it is unclear what you are trying to do.

Comment: I have edited the code to remove some of the t1=s and t2=s, also the code isn't to add up every node, rather it is to create a new tree(Still t1) where every node has the value of the sums of t1s and t2s original node in that place.

Comment: Also here is the error message: error:                                                                                ``` invalid operands to binary + (have ‘node_t *’ {aka ‘struct node_s *’} and ‘node_t *’ {aka ‘struct node_s *’})
   33 |     return addTree(t1->rightchild, t2->rightchild)+addTree(t1->rightchild, t2->leftchild)+addTree(t1->leftchild, t2->rightchild)+addTree(t1->leftchild, t2->leftchild);         ```
      |   node_t * {aka struct node_s *}          node_t * {aka struct node_s *}

Comment: The error message is telling you that it doesn't make sense to add together two pointers.  The error message is correct.  You can add a pointer to an integer to get another pointer, but it makes no sense to add two pointers.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work.  It uses a little trick so we only need a few null checks instead of many.

```c
node_t * addTree(const node_t * t1, const node_t * t2)
{
  if (t1 == NULL && t2 == NULL) { return NULL; }

  const node_t nullNode = {};
  if (t1 == NULL) { t1 = &nullNode; }
  if (t2 == NULL) { t2 = &nullNode; }

  node_t * r = malloc(sizeof(node_t));
  r->data = t1->data + t2->data;
  r->leftchild = addTree(t1->leftchild, t2->leftchild);
  r->rightchild = addTree(t1->rightchild, t2->rightchild);
  return r;
}
```